# Assign multiple named ranges to multiple range arrays

Tags: excel, vba

I'm kinda new here, but here is what I'm trying to do.

I have a book lets pretend its a warehouse book for inventory, and we have different divisions in our enterprise, I have master sheet with all the goods and some sheets covering those divisions for distribution of goods between them.

My idea is to have a drop down list for each item type in book for separate divisions so i need macro to assign/reassign named range for each item.

[I have 2 columns first with stock number and second with serial number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6w77R.png) , i need to put all the same serial number in the named range of one of stock numbers. if i have two or more serial numbers i need to put an array of serial numbers in named range of one stock number.
Stock numbers are in C column and serial numbers are in D column
I've tried this code

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim r As Range

LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

For Each r In Range("C2:C" & LastRow)
    Range(r.Offset(0, 1), r.Offset(0, 1)).Name = r.Value
Next r
End Sub
```

But thats not realy working, and assigns only one serial number per one named range of stock numbers

================================================================
So i ran this code you proposed in your updated version and struck some problems

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    
    Dim this As Worksheet: Set this = Sheets("ALFA")'renamed this for my book'
    Dim that As Worksheet: Set that = Sheets("STORAGE")'renamed that for my book'
    serialNumbers = that.Range(that.Columns(3), that.Columns(4))'Could not find method Unique(and there is no mentions about'
                                                      'it in MS documentation) for Application object so i changed it to just Range'

    
    For r = 2 To this.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        
        buffer = ""
        comma = ""
        stockNumber = this.Cells(r, 3)
            
        For x = 2 To UBound(serialNumbers)
        
            If serialNumbers(x, 1) = stockNumber Then
                buffer = buffer & comma & serialNumbers(x, 2)
                comma = ","
                End If
            
            Next
        
        this.Cells(r, 4).Validation.Delete
        this.Cells(r, 4).Validation.Add _'After doing everything it strucks with Run time error 1004 
            Type:=xlValidateList, _        '/Application-defined or object-defined error in this
            AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _'hole'
            Formula1:=buffer               'block'
        
        Next
        
End Sub
```

And sometimes code just hangs my excel application for atleast 3 mins, i think it's because there is no limit for cells to look up to and eventualy it tries to give all the cells in D:D a validation check

Comment: Not sure what you mean by multiple values per named range and overwriting values. It should just give each cell in `D2:D & LastRow` the name of the corresponding cell in `C`. I'm not sure how this would help however.

Comment: I mean every named range should have an array if value per category is not single.                                        We could see that in example with DDG_33

Comment: why are you finding LastCol?  I don't see you use it. As far as I can tell your code will go through each cell in C2:C and then create a named range one column over (D), with the name of the range being whatever is in column C. Is that you are trying to do?  For instance, if C2 contained "test", then this code would create a named range in D2 call test, which you could reference, and using that reference (for instance, =test in a formula or Range("test").value ) would return whatever is in D2, but this code doesn't change the value of D2, just names it.

Comment: I've used LastCol from someone else's code, and I agree that it's unnecessary
It fitted multiple column needs, but not my needs

Comment: @Chris Strickland and additionally, my code is doing just what you say, but there is more than 1 value per named range, so it's just replacing last value.

Comment: ok.  Now, in the image you shared, there are no multiple values, just one value for each DDG number.  It's hard to suggest revisions if we can't understand the data layout.  I would suggest that you create a google doc that matches the layout so that I can see what you are looking at.

Comment: @Chris Strickland here is model of my book and starting data that will expand with time
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/105MOB82ds9WVQvtuqin04iNd5BWWxjRh/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=109574637051259698533&rtpof=true&sd=true

Comment: @Chris Strickland And to be fair, i had multiple values in my example, you can see it at DDG_33 stock number.
Sorry if previous link vas invalid.
Here is new one.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/105MOB82ds9WVQvtuqin04iNd5BWWxjRh/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=109574637051259698533&rtpof=true&sd=true

Comment: Ok, I didn't notice the duplicate record in the image.  This workbook helps a lot.  So you have two columns, C and D, and you need to get a list of all values in D that match the entries in C.  This is actually simple enough to not need code, but you may have more requirements.  I'm going to start an answer with just a very basic set of formulas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if you want to set the validation, it is possible to set dynamic ranges BUT the validation won't accept a text list, for instance "one, two, three".  The validation is looking for an array of values, and unfortunately it is tricky to pass a dynamic array using formulas only.  You can set it up to do a dynamic range, but that would have to point to a range of cells that contain the needed values one per cell.

However, before you set all that up it's probably just easier to set the validation entirely in code.  See [this google sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1i9BgHq1xagrySiF9ebHrxfjEMbw5rN6UQqexGopKIuc/edit?usp=sharing), which just contains the layout for reference.  I have the complete list of items in Column 1 & 2 of the sheet (Item, Stock Number) and the complete list of serial numbers in columns 5 & 6 (Stock Number, Serial Number).

Then I run this code:

```
Sub setValidation()
    
    Dim this As Worksheet: Set this = Sheets("demo")
    Dim that As Worksheet: Set that = Sheets("lookups")
    serialNumbers = Application.Unique(that.Range(that.Columns(5), that.Columns(6)))
    
    For r = 2 To this.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        
        buffer = ""
        comma = ""
        stockNumber = this.Cells(r, 3)
            
        For x = 2 To UBound(serialNumbers)
        
            If serialNumbers(x, 1) = stockNumber Then
                buffer = buffer & comma & serialNumbers(x, 2)
                comma = ","
                End If
            
            Next
        
        this.Cells(r, 4).Validation.Delete
        this.Cells(r, 4).Validation.Add _
            Type:=xlValidateList, _
            AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
            Formula1:=buffer
        
        Next
    
End Sub
```

We assign some worksheet variables to make it easier to reference them, and then put the stock number/serial number combos into an array (with UNIQUE so I don't have to check for duplicates).

Then I run through the range that needs the validations (demo column 4), getting the stock number from column 3 and then using that stock number to find all serial numbers that match, concatenating them into a string and then using that string to set the validation.

Use Validation.Delete before setting the validation to avoid stacking rules.

Assuming that your version of Excel doesn't have UNIQUE, you can use INTERSECT to control the size of the serialNumbers array, like this:

```
Sub setValidation()
    
    Dim this As Worksheet: Set this = Sheets("demo")
    Dim that As Worksheet: Set that = Sheets("lookups")
    serialNumbers = Intersect( _
        that.Range(that.Columns(5), that.Columns(6)), _
        that.UsedRange _
    )
    
    For r = 2 To this.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        
        buffer = ""
        comma = ""
        stockNumber = this.Cells(r, 3)
            
        For x = 2 To UBound(serialNumbers)
        
            If serialNumbers(x, 1) = stockNumber Then
                buffer = buffer & comma & serialNumbers(x, 2)
                comma = ","
                End If
            
            Next
        
        this.Cells(r, 4).Validation.Delete
        this.Cells(r, 4).Validation.Add _
            Type:=xlValidateList, _
            AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
            Formula1:=buffer
        
        Next
    
End Sub
```

Assuming you do have UNIQUE and FILTER in your Excel version, there is another way to do it, using the EVALUATE function to access the Excel function engine.  In this case we will just write out a formula just like we would in a cell, and then evaluate it from VBA.  Unless specified, evaluate occurs in the context of the active sheet, so that's what I use `that.evaluate` in this code:

```
Sub setValidation()
    
    Dim expr As String
    Dim this As Worksheet: Set this = Sheets("demo")
    Dim that As Worksheet: Set that = Sheets("lookups")
    
    For r = 2 To this.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        
        stockNumber = this.Cells(r, 3)
        
        expr = "Textjoin("","", true, Unique(Filter(F:F, E:E=""" & stockNumber & """)))"
        serialNumbers = that.Evaluate(expr)
        
        this.Cells(r, 4).Validation.Delete
        this.Cells(r, 4).Validation.Add _
            Type:=xlValidateList, _
            AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
            Formula1:=serialNumbers
        
        Next
    
End Sub
```

In this case, we use FILTER to return ONLY the serial numbers that match a stock number, UNIQUE to make sure there are no duplicates, and then TEXTJOIN to create a list from that, and then we can just pass that result straight to the validation.

===================================================

Original answer, shows how to get a list of all serial numbers for a specific stock number using only excel formulas, but it became clear that this wouldn't be sufficient, since the lists were going to be used to set validation.  Left here for completeness.

So you have two columns, C and D, and you need to get a list of all values in D that match the entries in C.  This is actually simple enough to not need code, but you may have more requirements.  I'm going to start an answer with just a very basic set of formulas.  See this [google sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Y8GYsjSSbZAtqs7nnRO_nBMAqA0vZkrDpwfhuX0xsVA/edit#gid=0).

To get a unique list of the stock numbers, I have used `UNIQUE(C:C)` in G1.  This will produce the list in column G.

Then in column H, I have used TEXTJOIN+UNIQUE+FILTER to produce a comma separated list of serial numbers.  FILTER takes one input array (in this case Col D) and filters it with another array (Col C) and a condition (the serial number) to return a list of matches, and wrapping that in UNIQUE makes sure that the result array contains only unique values.  Wrapping that in TEXTJOIN converts the result array into text.

What I'm not entirely clear on is your need for a named range, or what you will do with the multiple rows in a sheet.  For instance, STORAGE rows 35 & 36 are both for DDG_33:

```
DDG_33  0BV1111
DDG_33  0AV0951
```

and if you ran some code to produce a list of values and put it in D35 you would have:

```
DDG_33  0BV1111, 0AV0951
DDG_33  0AV0951
```

but you would still have two entries for DDG_33.  If you ran the code again, you would have

```
DDG_33  0BV1111, 0AV0951, 0AV0951
DDG_33  0AV0951
```

and so forth in an infinite loop.  It seems like you would need to take the list of unique stock numbers and put them on a different sheet, along with the list of matching serial numbers, but just clarify what you want to do and I can update my answer.

Comment: My need in named range is in drop down menus, cause i need to give each division different goods and those goods have different stock and serial numbers.
Few items with same stock and serial number and with different quantity could be presented in different divisions , and i want a macro that will go thru full list of items and create named range. so i could use INDIRECT for stock number and choose right serial number

Comment: Ok, so what you really want to do is have one dropdown that lets you select stock numbers, and then and then a second dropdown that loads the serial numbers depending on which stock number is selected, is that right?

Comment: stock number could be automatically caught with VLOOKUP(last sheet in my book). I made it because I needed reliable way to make named ranges, if I leave it with only items names I will struck  inevitable difference between named ranges and item names whereas I need to address to something with finite complexity.

Comment: To be honest, I really don't think you need named ranges at all, but it's a little hard to tell, because I'm still trying to follow what you are trying to do.  The last thing you were saying is that you needed to populate some dropdown menus.  Describe that part.

Comment: I have full list of items on first sheet, and have separate lists of items distributed among each division. Drop down menu is there for distributing purposes, because both events(filling basic sheet and distribution among divisions) are separated in time. And then data collects(like total quantities divided) and  again on first sheet to be seen in total. Drop down menu is for easy to choose what kind of item(namely serial number) i'm giving out for different divisions.

Comment: When you say drop down menus you mean the data validation in a cell, like on Alpha!D:D, correct?

Comment: On the assumption that that is what you need, I went ahead and updated the answer to include some code.

Comment: Yep, I need data validation on every sheet(excluding STORAGE) on D:D, so i updated my answer because it needs extened clarification of problems

Comment: Ok, Application.Unique might not exist in your version.  Try this: `application.WorksheetFunction.Unique`.  But even without the unique, the code still works for me, it just has a broader range to go over BUT our data isn't the same, either.  Where it fails, can you tell me the values of `r` and `buffer`?

Comment: Thanks a lot, I broke it, I fixed it) (i removed "that." in `(that.Columns(5), that.Columns(6))`)
I deleted a lot of blank rows and it improved in speed, but I guess with rise of number of rows problem will be back again.
Again thanks a lot=)

Comment: Glad to hear it's working, and more rows will make it slower, but how many rows do you actually have?  It shouldn't be that slow.  Do this: right after the assignment of `serialNumbers`, and before you go into the `FOR r` loop, bring up the immediate window and type `? ubound(serialNumbers)` and tell me what the size of the array is.  Same with `this.UsedRange.Rows.Count`.

Comment: I gived you pretty much all of starting table data, so for start, its about 100 serial numbers  and division table are about 50 row(x8 divisions). For now it takes ~3 secs per sheet, so to  compete all placing of validation i need at least 24 secs

Comment: 100 is really not that many, and the r loop is constrained by usedRange.Rows.Count, so it shouldn't be slowing down there.  If you couldn't get unique to work the size of the serialNumber array would be over a million, so that might be the cause.  There is another way to do it, using EVALUATE to get vba to access the native Excel function.  Take a look at the edit I just made.

Comment: That's running crazy fast, but it writes #Value! error in each drop down menu(Validation check). here is some examples of watched expressions.
: stockNumber : "DDG_82" : Variant/String :
: expr : "Textjoin("," ,true,Unique(Filter(D:D,C:C="DDG_82")))" :  String
 : serialNumbers : Error 2015 : Variant/Error :
So, my idea is - I have no function FILTER in my excel(
I have only FILTER.XML embeded function in my version

Comment: It's possible you don't.  Try using unique or filter in a formula in the sheet to test for their presence.

Comment: made an edit that doesn't depend on UNIQUE or FILTER.

Comment: Thanks, it works like a rocket, also I added checks if buffer is empty to do nothing, only delete validation, and putted it into Worksheet_Change Sub, under condition of changing Name of item(B:B)

Comment: Great.  Glad it's working for you, and yes, you probably do need that check for the buffer being empty.  Before it was going to be an empty string that gets added to, but now it is possible for it to be empty or null or something.